# Double integrals to find area?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In my math textbook it's written that double integrals is used to find area. Is it true? I thought I'd used to find volume. If so, how is it used to find area?

Comment: What textbook is it?

Comment: I have another related version of this question in mind. Single integrals can be used to calculate line integrals (duh!) as well as areas (between curves). Now, I know that double integrals can be used to calculate areas as well. But can double integrals be used to compute volumes?

Comment: @AritraDas : Yes; that's how the definition of a double integral is usually motivated ($\displaystyle\int_R f\,dA$ is the volume of the solid bounded above by the surface $z=f(x,y)$, on the sides by the boundary of $R$, and below by $z=0$).

Comment: To the OP: The double-integral formula for the area of $R$ is $\displaystyle\int_R 1\,dA$. The triple-integral formula for the volume of a solid $S$ is $\displaystyle \int_S 1\,dV$.